# com.google.firebase:firebase- and com.google.android.gms:play-services decompiled class instead of source

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, google-play-services, android-studio-3.0

I'am using Android Studio 3.0 and i added the following libraries into gradle:

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
```

But when i jump into the source i can see only decompiled classes like:

```
private FirebaseAuth(FirebaseApp var1, zzdtw var2, zzdxh var3) {
    this.zzlzc = new Object();
    this.zzlyy = (FirebaseApp)zzbq.checkNotNull(var1);
    this.zzlza = (zzdtw)zzbq.checkNotNull(var2);
    this.zzlze = (zzdxh)zzbq.checkNotNull(var3);
    this.zzlwx = new CopyOnWriteArrayList();
    this.zzlyz = new CopyOnWriteArrayList();
    this.zzlzf = zzdxi.zzbqm();
    this.zzlzb = this.zzlze.zzbql();
    zzdwf var5;
    if(this.zzlzb != null && (var5 = this.zzlze.zzg(this.zzlzb)) != null) {
        this.zza(this.zzlzb, var5, false);
    }

}


public static Dialog zza(Activity var0, OnCancelListener var1) {
        ProgressBar var2;
        (var2 = new ProgressBar(var0, (AttributeSet)null, 16842874)).setIndeterminate(true);
        var2.setVisibility(0);
        Builder var3;
        (var3 = new Builder(var0)).setView(var2);
        var3.setMessage(zzu.zzi(var0, 18));
        var3.setPositiveButton("", (OnClickListener)null);
        AlertDialog var4 = var3.create();
        zza(var0, var4, "GooglePlayServicesUpdatingDialog", var1);
        return var4;
    }
```

Some functions have the proper name, some don't, but no function have documentation nor readable source inside them

I tried to roll back to version 10.2.4 but nothing changes.

Comment: Those are obfuscated classes, you wont be able to view them

Comment: I had a simular problem with the com.android.support libs but after some update it started to show the source. This is how are supposed to be?

Comment: Yes this is how it is suppose to see, Google Play Services are not open source so they obfuscate the code to protect their proprietary information

Comment: You can answer, I will accept it, I was looking for this for months